# How to find a string in a HTML document, ignoring whitespace?

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find a string "USB 2 ports" in a number of HTML pages. The problem is that the strings have a large amount of white space before them - sometimes 4, 20 or even 50 white space characters.

The following works with a single white space character preceding my string:

```
soup.find(text=' USB 2 ports')
```

Note the single space before the USB.

How can I tell Beautiful Soup's `find()` to find my string while ignoring all preceding white space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a [regular expression](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument) to search for the text regardless of leading and trailing whitespace:

```python
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\s*%s\s*' % 'USB 2 ports')
result = soup.find(text=pattern)
```

For example:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("""
... <html>
...   <body>
...     <ul>
...       <li>
...         USB 2 ports
...       </li>
...       <li>
...         Firewire ports
...       </li>
...       <li>
...         HDMI ports
...       </li>
...     </ul>
...   </body>
... </html>
... """)
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\s*%s\s*' % 'USB 2 ports')
>>> soup.find(text=pattern)
u'\n        USB 2 ports\n      '
```

**EDIT**: I've changed the code above to explicitly assign the result of `soup.find()` to a variable, in the hopes of making it clearer what's happening. I originally modelled the code in my answer after your example code in the interests of clarity, but I now suspect you may be somewhat confused about what that code actually does.

Comment: For some reason this returns none, I tried it with another string value and I got <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x00000000028C2C50> when I tried tried to print pattern

Comment: @Ninja2k I think there must be some other problem with your code, then; it works perfectly for me (the demo I added above is a direct copy-paste from the Python 2.7.3 interpreter).

Comment: Also: yes, you will get that when you print `pattern`, because it *is* a regex pattern. The return value of `soup.find(text=pattern)` is the result.

Comment: Agh yes yes I need to make that equal to a variable and print its result. Now I see it works, perfect.